# How to find overridden master page elements?

Tags: adobe-indesign, master-page

Via <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+click one can override master page elements of an InDesign element, and by deleting it and re-applying the master page one can undo the overriding. But how can one find the overridden elements other than just "knowing" which elements should be from the master page but are editable on the current page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start setting up dedicated master layers when creating masters. Even though the master layers are visible in layers panel when working in a regular page, only the items you have released from master can be selected / will be listed in your master layers.

Comment: Simple but effective, I like it. Too bad that won't work retroactively...

Comment: yeah, a lot of things are like that in Indesign! I find often the most time is spent figuring out how to do stuff and not actually do them. Rebuilding a document can be a pain but also very satisfying when it works just the way you want it. Good luck.

Comment: Unfortunately so... The catch is this means one has to manually merge the master-layer into another one if one wants to export to a PDF with layers, and then _not_ save the InDesign document.

Comment: ..What kind of document / project are you making?

Comment: Documentation that is printed on a form by us but must contain that form itself as well, thus two layers.